# How do I handle my posted XY question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The specific question:
[What do "ACard AHCI SATA low-level driver" meaning? What is "ACard"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478108/what-do-acard-ahci-sata-low-level-driver-meaning-what-is-acard)

I'm aware that is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

The actual problem is "How can I remove all initramfs modules that are not needed for most desktop PCs boot from USB; simply using `lsmod` will not work because I need to use my initramfs on most desktop PCs not on my PC only.", but it seems such a question is too broad by our rules.

Can anyone help me reword my [specific question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478108/what-do-acard-ahci-sata-low-level-driver-meaning-what-is-acard)?

Comment: "Most desktop PCs" seems broad to me; it'd seem easier (to me) to answer given an actual PC to solve against, or at least a set of peripherals.

Comment: @JeffSchaller "at least a set of peripherals" , If I reword my question to  "How can I remove all initramfs modules that are not needed for most desktop PCs **boot from USB**" is enough clear for you?

Answer (score 3):

While I didn't vote on your question, it does seem unclear to me in the following ways:

- you've asked multiple distinct questions:

  1. What do “ACard AHCI SATA low-level driver” meaning?
  2. What is “ACard”?
  3. Is this module never used(real loaded) in initramfs for desktop PC?
  4. If it never use in desktop PC,I want remove it from my initramfs.
  5. I want my initramfs work in most desktop PC.

Questions are free and easy, so if you want to know what "ACard" means, ask *that* -- with whatever *context* you feel is appropriate, and you'll see it would have been an easy Answer (as sebasth [commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478108/what-do-acard-ahci-sata-low-level-driver-meaning-what-is-acard#comment873928_478108)). Don't burden that question with other problems to be addressed, just the context: "I'm building an initramfs and came across this (modinfo output here) driver; what does `ACard` signify in this description?"

- When your real question is "How can I remove all initramfs modules that are not needed for most desktop PCs", consider making that the title and then use the body of the question to explain what you're up to and what the problem(s) are.

I can't speak for all of the answerers (or voters) on the site, but the wording of "most desktop PC's" *sounds* broad to me. From a high level, I'd suggest either:

- including as *many* modules as you can, in hopes of supporting "most" configurations, and then accepting the slower load time -- or
- *minimizing* the included modules and waiting for complaints from users that something in particular didn't work.  What happens if a very important user has a "slow USB storage device" that they *want* to use?

Comment: "What happens if..." I'm very sorry for so bad XY problem, my original question is "How to ensure new PC support my using Debian before buy it in physical store" but it seems still broad? I'm worry initramfs boot speed problem due I need test new PC in physical store. If my test too slow, I may be rejected by seller.

Answer (score 2):

Why would that be too broad? Just edit your existing question, add more detail and explain what you need to do and it will be entered in the reopen queue. Then, when 4 users vote for reopening, it can be reopened.